# Is comparing motherboards primarily opinion based?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I am seeing people ask questions about Intel and AMD motherboards and trying to compare the features.

Do we entertain these opinion based questions?

This is tricky to flag. We know that motherboard is hardware and can be asked on the site, but when they ask which is better (Intel vs AMD) this is kind of opinion based or they are making us to read materials to evaluate the same.

Should this be answered or closed/flagged as off-topic?